# Google maps + cordova_not showing the map

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, gps

So i just want to show map with fixed parameters. Screen just shows the header image and that's it. 
This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAvK_y6sDBwuqXCQzTSg1Z953MhuvnQ-LI&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initializeMap() {
   var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  }
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<title>Rock Werchter</title>
</head>
<body onload="initializeMap()">
<script type="text/javascript">
if(sessionStorage.u)
document.write("Welcome " + sessionStorage.getItem('u'));

function doOnOrientationChange()
{
switch(window.orientation) 
{  
  case -90:
  case 90:
    alert('landscape');
    break; 
  default:
    alert('portrait');
    break; 
 }
}
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doOnOrientationChange);
</script>
<img src="img/header.jpg" width="100%" height="50" />
<div id="map" height=100 width=100></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have added following permissions to AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

and i have added the following in my config file

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
```